# How to calculate a field upon row creation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, feature-class

I want to create a calculated field that will auto populate whenever a new row is inserted into a feature class.  I can do this with the Field Calculator, but that requires manual intervention.

Is there anything like the calculated column in MSSQL where you enter a formula and the result is calculated on a read, but not persisted?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  What exactly is your question?  Please [edit] your question to include how you've calculated your new field, and a bit more info about what you're trying to do and where you are stuck.  What is your feature class stored in - shapefile, file geodatabase, enterprise geodatabase?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only way to do this is by using an actual database as the backend for your feature class and doing the automatic calculation there.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into [Attribute Assistant](http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/) for this as long as you are editing within ArcMap and not though ArcGIS Online or ArcGIS Pro.  My organisation uses it predominately for grabbing the attributes of a nearby feature and population a field within the one we are editing.

This is the description of Attribute Assistant

"The Attribute Assistant Add-In is an editor extension that uses a series of predefined methods to populate attributes when you create new features or edit existing features in a geodatabase."

Depending on your experience level it could be quite a learning curve but the benefits of it are great. This is a [list of all the methods](http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/documentation/methods-all-methods/) (things it can do).  You could probably use the "Expression" method adn set it to the "on create rule".